# Unable to set c++ standard (c++17) in cmake 3.9.2

Tags: c++, cmake, c++17, clang++

When using cmake (3.9.2) the command:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
```

does not correctly add the flag -std=c++17.

The macro __cplusplus expands to 199711. I also get errors with regards to c++11 features like initalization_lists.

I am using clang++ 5.0.0. I would also like to be able to use clang-tidy from cmake via:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_CLANG_TIDY "clang-tidy;-checks=*")
```

This only seems to be an issue after upgrading cmake from version 3.7.1.

I can't seem to locate any documentation on a relevant change between the versions. Am I missing something? Do clang 5.0 and cmake 3.9.2 have some compatibility issues?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to set  `CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED` to on?

Comment: Yes. No change unfortunately.

Comment: Can you please add the output of `message("CMAKE_CXX17_STANDARD_COMPILE_OPTION = ${CMAKE_CXX17_STANDARD_COMPILE_OPTION}")`? If it's `-std=c++1z` you can try `set(CMAKE_CXX17_STANDARD_COMPILE_OPTION "-std=c++17")` (the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html#cxx17) mentions a change to clang 5 which probably is not reflected yet in CMake).

Comment: The ${CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_COMPILE_OPTION} variable is empty when printed "CMAKE_CXX17_STANDARD_COMPILE_OPTION =".

Comment: Using
    set(CMAKE_CXX17_STANDARD_COMPILE_OPTION "-std=c++17") does not seem to result in any observable change for me.

Comment: Strange. Can you please give more details about your environment? Which OS, IDE, ...?

Comment: Using OSX Sierra. Not using an IDE. CMake is version 3.9.2. Compiler is Clang 5.0.0.

Comment: Same here. CMake 3.9.5, Clang 5.0.0, when checking compile_commands.json I always see that clang is called with `-std=gnu++1z` option

Comment: clang? Or apple-clang?